# Jackson - generic TreeSet is not serialized

Tags: java, generics, serialization, jackson

I am trying to serialize object having the following field:

```
private TreeSet<TimeSlot<T>> counterTimeSlotSet = 
    new TreeSet<TimeSlot<T>>(
            new Comparator<TimeSlot<T>>(){
                @Override
                public int compare(TimeSlot<T> cb1, TimeSlot<T> cb2) {
                    return cb1.getPeriod().compareTo(cb2.getPeriod());
                }
            });
```

The serializition code is below:

```
    BaseSlidingWindow<BasicVelocityCounter> window1 = 
        new BaseSlidingWindow<BasicVelocityCounter>(
                BasicVelocityCounter.class, slidingWindowConfig);
    ...

    // jackson serializer test
    Version version = new Version(1, 0, 0, "SNAPSHOT");
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("ZORRO", version);
    module = module.addSerializer(new DateTimeSerializer());
    // and so on...
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(module);

    mapper.writeValue(new File("C:\\tmp\\window1.json"), window1);
```

The problem is that `window1` member of type `TreeSet<TimeSlot<T>>` is not serialized.
No exceptions appear in the log.
I am just getting json that does not contain the `TreeSet<TimeSlot<T>>` member.

Debugging jackson code did not lead me anywhere. **I wonder what needs to be done in order to get the `TreeSet<TimeSlot<T>>` serialized?**

**EDIT**

My `BaseSlidingWindow` class definition looks as follows:

```
public class BaseSlidingWindow<T extends ICountable<T>> 
                        implements ISlidingWindow<T>{

    boolean dirty = false;

    private DateTime createdOn;
    private DateTime updatedOn;
    private DateTime windowLifeStart;
    private DateTime windowLifeEnd;

    private final SlidingWindowConfig slidingWindowConfig;

    private TreeSet<TimeSlot<T>> counterTimeSlotSet = 
    new TreeSet<TimeSlot<T>>(
            new Comparator<TimeSlot<T>>(){
                @Override
                public int compare(TimeSlot<T> cb1, TimeSlot<T> cb2) {
                    return cb1.getPeriod().compareTo(cb2.getPeriod());

                }
            });

    private final Class firstSeenDataType;

    // constructor, accessors and IFS implementations
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @Programmer Bruce, where are you? :)

Comment: How does `BaseSlidingWindow` look like? It may not have anything to do with type `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any public fields or getters in `BaseSlidingWindow`. As such, it has no observable properties to serialize.
If this is the problem, the easiest way is to add `@JsonProperty` before `counterTimeSlotSet` and other properties you want to serialize.

Alternative methods include adding "getter" methods (like `getCounterTimeSlotSet`) or changing the default visibility settings to also include non-public fields.

Comment: I skipped posting the accessors, but they are there. If this is the case what went wrong?

Comment: @aviad So `BaseSlidingWindow` _does_ have a `getCounterTimeSlotSet()` method?

Comment: @matts, yes it does. I found the problem and seems like one of the classes down the object graph had a `protected` setter causing `TimeSlot` not to be reflected properly.

Comment: Odd. Missing setter should not (by default) prevent a getter from being detected. But good that you figured it out nonetheless.